# Python: How to iterate through each value in two lists, count the occurrences that value is < 22 in the 1st list OR < 27 in the 2nd list?

Tags: python, list, loops, count

I'm confused on how to iterate through each value in two lists and which loop to use and how for this. Please help!!

I have two lists (`datalist_country` and `datalist_urban`). In my main function, I assigned each list to a text file. The values with the same index (e.g. 23) on each list refer to the mileage of the same car in the country vs on urban roads.

I'm trying to use some sort of loop (probably `while` would be best?). My end goal is to return a count of how many cars get *either* less than 22 mpg on country roads or less than 27 mpg on urban roads.

```
 def mydatacount(datalist_country, datalist_urban):
    count = []
    for value in datalist_country:
        num = float(value)
        if num > 22:
            count.append(value)
    for value in datalist_urban:
        num = float(value)
        if num > 27:
            count.append(value)
    print(len(count))
```

Comment: Are these lists a list of lists? You say *The same index (ie [23]) on each list refers to the mileage* but then you are iterating through as if it is just a simple list of strings. Post an example of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function can help you with that. It take as many iterables (such as lists) as you want and creates an iterator that gives you tuples, where the n-th tuple contains the n-th element of each list and the order in the tuple is the same as that of the iterators passed to the function. This way you can iterate through multiple lists at once. Note that the zip-iterator ends, when one of the iterators passed is exhausted.

Also you stated you look for cars with less than 22 or 27 mpg, hence you need to check if num is less than that, not greater. The could would look like this:

```
def mydatacount(datalist_country, datalist_urban):
    count = 0
    for value_c, value_u in zip(datalist_country, datalist_urban):
        num_c = float(value_c)
        num_u = float(value_u)
        if num_c < 22 or num_u < 27:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `zip` function to create successive pairs of your mileage, with a filter (`if` expression) that returns a one if the condition passes. `sum` takes its value from the [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and adds all the generated `1`s:

```
def mydatacount(datalist_country, datalist_urban):
    count = sum(1 for i in zip(datalist_country, datalist_urban) if float(i[0])<22 or float(i[1])<27)
    print(count)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `zip` and `sum`:

```
count = sum(1 for x, y in zip(datalist_country, datalist_urban) if float(x) < 22 or float(y) < 27)
```